# samba schema upgrade

Tags: server, samba, samba4

I'm running samba 4.3.11 on Ubuntu server Xenial. It's the only AD-DC in a windows domain that used to be hosted by a single Win2k3 server.

The AD schema version is 30, the functionality level is already raised to 2008_R2 (domain) and 2008 (forest).

```
ldbsearch -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb -b 'cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=domain,dc=com' -s base objectVersion
# record 1
dn: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=vswest,DC=intern
objectVersion: 30
```

How can I raise the schema version? I could not find anything on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by search by myself:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/AD_Schema_Version_Support

> To upgrade the schema version on a running Samba installation to 2012_R2, use this command:
>
> ```
> samba-tool domain schemaupgrade
> ```
>
> Note: This tool only works from 2008 R2. In order to upgrade from earlier versions, the ldf files must be manually sourced from the Windows adprep tool and run with the --ldf-file= option.

Comment: Despite this being documented in the Samba wiki, there appears to be no subcommand "schemaupgrade" for "samba-tool domain", at least not in the version mentioned in the question (4.3.x). Running this command in that version just displays usage of the command.